# esp32 printf channel through uart (esp-idf)

Tags: c, freertos, esp32, esp-idf

I try to disable all logs on my program, 
I did disable esp logs 
but when I use `printf` in my channel and open `make monitor`
`printf` still works.

how and why?
I want to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The system logs and printf are two different things over here. In your project sdkconfig file check if the parameter '**CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_DEFAULT**' is set.

This defines where all your console outputs are dumped into.

In your case you want to disable all the printf logs, you can try setting '**CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_NONE**=y'.

If you are doing it thourgh make menuconfig of esp-idf, it will come under - *component config > ESP32-Specific > UART for console output (Default: UART0, TX=GPIO1, RX=GPIO3) > None*

Hope I answered to your question. :)